# Asymptotics of number of points of elliptic curves over finite fields

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

For an elliptic curve $E$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, let $a_q(E) = q+1 - |E(\mathbb F_q)|$. Hasse--Weil bound tells us that $|a_q(E)| \leq 2 \sqrt{q}$.

I am interesting in knowing how large/small can $2 \sqrt{q} - a_q$ be. For instance, is there a sequence of primes $(p_k)$ and elliptic curves $E_k$ over $\mathbb F_{p_k}$ such that
$$b(E_k) := (2 \sqrt{p_k} - a_{p_k}(E_k)) / \log(p_k) \to 0$$ ?

I know that 1) Sato--Tate distribution describes the distribution of $a_p(E) / (2 \sqrt{p})$, but here we are looking at the *difference* between $a_p$ and $2 \sqrt{p}$, not the quotient, and 2) supersingular curves show that $b(E_k)$ can go to infinity.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're asking but seems related: some bounds on the number of primes $p$ for which $\lvert a_p(E) \rvert = \lfloor 2 \sqrt{p} \rfloor$ for some CM elliptic curves $E$, assuming RH for certain Hecke $L$-functions: https://www.math.umd.edu/~pwerthei/files/papers/extremalprimes.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a fixed prime power $q = p^n$ (with $p$ prime), Waterhouse (1969) gives a complete description of which numbers can occur as $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for some elliptic curve $E$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. In particular, the extremal cases $a_q = \pm 2 \sqrt{q}$ do occur (for some $E$) whenever $q$ is a perfect square (i.e., whenever $n$ is even).

Rück (1987) goes further and describes all possible group structures for $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$. These papers were brought to my attention by [this answer of Joe Silverman](https://mathoverflow.net/a/317538/31308) to a related question on MathOverflow.

References:

1. [MR0265369](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0265369), Waterhouse, William C., Abelian varieties over finite fields. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 2 1969 521–560.
2. [MR0890272](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0890272), Rück, Hans-Georg, A note on elliptic curves over finite fields. Math. Comp. 49 (1987), no. 179, 301–304.

Comment: Thanks. The result of Deuring (1941) seems to be sufficient for my question.